# How to prevent the user from choosing some file types?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to prevent the user to choose some file types when he opens NSOpenpanel.
what i can do at the moment is preventing him from accessing all the files and allow some but i want to allow all the files except some.

```
NSOpenpanel*Openpane = [NSOpenpanl openpanel];
[Openpanel setAllowFileTypes(NSArray*)];
```

but i want the user to choose all the files except files not choose some files out of all the files.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to, for example, allow a user to open jpeg files, but disallow specific jpeg files like "foo.jpg"? Or are you saying you want them to open all the jpeg files in a given directory? Your last sentence is unclear. Also, you should properly capitalize your sentences. They're hard to read, otherwise.

Comment: i want to prevent the user from choosing MP3 when he opens up a NSOpanel,that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a delegate for the panel. `NSOpenPanel` inherits a `delegate` property from its superclass `NSSavePanel`.

In the delegate, implement either:

```
- (BOOL) panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL*)url;
```

or:

```
- (BOOL) panel:(id)sender validateURL:(NSURL*)url error:(NSError**)outError;
```

You should use the first one if you can decide whether a given URL should be enabled quickly and efficiently. It will be called frequently. It controls whether or not a given URL is selectable in the panel.

You should use the second one if your decision is slow or requires significant CPU or I/O. It is only called when the user clicks the Open button. That's not the best user experience. It's better to prevent the user from making a bad choice than to let them make a bad choice and reject it at the last moment.

All of that said, it's kind of weird to allow a user to select *any* kind of file *except* MP3s. Is there really no other restriction?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a list of acceptable file types by calling `[-NSOpenPanel setAllowedFileTypes:]` and passing in an array of allowed file extensions. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH4-SW6) for details:

> A file type can be a common file extension, or a UTI. A nil value indicates that any file type can be used. The default value is nil.

If you want to filter out some filenames and not others, I think you can use the `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` method [`-panel:shouldEnableURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008249-CH1-SW4)

> For NSOpenPanel delegates, asks the delegate whether the specified URL should be enabled in the panel.

Comment: well,i don't want to allow files in array but i want to disallow files in array,that what i mentioned but you didn't understand.

Comment: OK, I had assumed you wanted other audio file types and could list those, but not MP3s. Would the above work? Create a delegate and use the `-panel:shouldEnableURL:` method?

Comment: look,all i want is the method that enables me to disallow some file types.

Comment: That's what the delegate method does. It passes you every URL that it's going to show in the current directory and lets you decide whether that file should be included or excluded. You can check each file's type to see if it's an MP3 and if so, exclude it.